# Getting inspiration for a first short film

Tags: video, short

I have a large amount of photo and video kit, and have always enjoyed casual photography and videography.

I really want to make a short film, just for the sake of it, for the enjoyment of the process etc. 
But I have no Idea what I want to produce.

Where should I look for inspiration?

One caveat:
I live in a small but dull town, and don't really have many friends here, so it would need to be mostly non people-based.

Comment: Create a documentary about the history of the place.

Comment: Could create a piece just using either iconic or artistic shots of the town to a nice piece of music, as above do a documentary on the town. maybe your town has something or someone who does something extraordinary like a blacksmith, woodworking, makes shoes etc, do a docu on them and tell their story